# UITextField not updating to change in ObservableObject (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, combine, observableobject

I am trying to make a UITextView that edits a value `currentDisplayedAddress`. The value is also changed by other views, and I want the UITextView to update its text when that occurs.

The view initializes correctly, and I can edit `currentDisplayedAddress` from `AddressTextField` with no problem and trigger relevant view updates. However, when the value is changed by other views, the textField's text does not change, even though `textField.text` prints the correct updated value inside `updateUIView` and other views update accordingly.

I have no idea what may have caused this. Any help is extremely appreciated.

```
struct AddressTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    var commit: () -> Void
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserDataModel

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AddressTextField>) -> UITextField {
        textField.text = self.userData.currentDisplayedAddress
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AddressTextField>) {
        if self.textField.text != self.userData.currentDisplayedAddress {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textField.text = self.userData.currentDisplayedAddress
            }
        }
    }

   (...)

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var addressTextField: AddressTextField

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            addressTextField.userData.currentDisplayedAddress = textField.text ?? String()
            addressTextField.commit()
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create `UITextField` as property, because `AddressTextField` struct can be recreated during parent update. The `makeUIView` is exactly the place to create UI-instances, the representable is handling its reference on your behalf.

So here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct AddressTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    var commit: () -> Void = {}
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserDataModel

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AddressTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.text = self.userData.currentDisplayedAddress
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textField: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AddressTextField>) {
        if textField.text != self.userData.currentDisplayedAddress {
            textField.text = self.userData.currentDisplayedAddress
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var addressTextField: AddressTextField
        init(_ addressTextField: AddressTextField) {
            self.addressTextField = addressTextField
        }
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            addressTextField.userData.currentDisplayedAddress = textField.text ?? String()
            addressTextField.commit()
            return true
        }
    }
}
```